# Does Weblogic 10.3 support EJB2.0 Specification?

Tags: weblogic, ejb

Does Weblogic 10.3 support EJB2.0 Sepcification?

Answer (score 2):

The EJB3.0 specification is supposed to be backwards compatible with both 1.x and 2.x, and Weblogic 10.3 claims to be fully EJB3.0 compliant.
So, without actually testing myself, it really should work.